# SQL: Running total with group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, cumulative-sum

I have a dataset that has two date columns for each transaction. An invoice date and a charge date. I am trying to do a cumulative or running total of the table in sql.

**Data table looks like this**
InvoiceDate ChargeDate TransactionID
jan/1/2021  jan/1/2021 11111
jan/1/2021  jan/1/2021 55555
jan/1/2021  Feb/1/2021 11111
jan/1/2021  Feb/1/2021 22222
jan/1/2021  Feb/1/2021 33333
jan/1/2021  Feb/1/2021 44444
Feb/1/2021  jan/1/2021 11111
Feb/1/2021  jan/1/2021 22222
Feb/1/2021  jan/1/2021 33333
Feb/1/2021  jan/1/2021 44444
Feb/1/2021  Feb/1/2021 55555

I want the **output** in this format
InvoiceDate ChargeDate cumulativeCount
jan/1/2021  jan/1/2021 2
jan/1/2021  Feb/1/2021 5
Feb/1/2021  jan/1/2021 3
Feb/1/2021  Feb/1/2021 4

I tried the following code but it doesn't give me a running total. it gives me total of each of the two columns

```
    select
    chargeDate,
    InvoiceDate,
    Count(Distinct TransactionID) as CountofIDs
    from mytable1
where InvoiceDate<=InvoiceDate
    group by ChargeDate, InvoiceDate
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . If I following correctly, you want aggregation with a window function.

```
select invoicedate, chargedate,
       count(*) as cnt_on_dates,
       sum(count(*)) over (partition by invoicedate order by chargedate) as cumulative_count
from t
group by invoicedate, chargedate;
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that over function is not supported. I believe its ver 2005